# Why do two linear regression lines look the same when one dataset is scaled and one is not?

Tags: scikit-learn, linear-regression

This code generates two plots but they look the same even though the first is the raw data and the second is the scaled version of the data. I don't understand why the Y axis values don't overpower the X axis values in the raw data plot.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

def loadSkewedData():
    skewedDF = pd.read_csv("skewedData.csv")
    return skewedDF
skewedDataDF = loadSkewedData()
scaler = MinMaxScaler()  # mean will be 0, std dev will be 1
scaledData = scaler.fit_transform(skewedDataDF)
scaledDataDF = pd.DataFrame(scaledData, columns=skewedDataDF.columns)

ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(skewedDataDF["BP Diastolic"], skewedDataDF["Annual Income"])
plt.title("BP Diastolic vs Annual Income, Raw (unscaled) Data")
plt.xlabel("BP Diastolic")
plt.ylabel("Annual Income")

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(np.array(skewedDataDF["BP Diastolic"]).reshape(-1, 1) , np.array(skewedDataDF["Annual Income"]).reshape(-1, 1) )

x_new = np.linspace(skewedDataDF["BP Diastolic"].min(), skewedDataDF["BP Diastolic"].max(), 100)
y_new = model.predict(x_new[:, np.newaxis])

ax.plot(x_new, y_new)    
plt.show()

#   Plot scaled data
ax = plt.axes()
ax.scatter(scaledDataDF["BP Diastolic"], scaledDataDF["Annual Income"])
plt.title("BP Diastolic vs Annual Income, Normalized (Min/Max) Data")
plt.xlabel("BP Diastolic")
plt.ylabel("Annual Income")
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(np.array(scaledDataDF["BP Diastolic"]).reshape(-1, 1) , np.array(scaledDataDF["Annual Income"]).reshape(-1, 1) )

x_new = np.linspace(scaledDataDF["BP Diastolic"].min(), scaledDataDF["BP Diastolic"].max(), 100)
y_new = model.predict(x_new[:, np.newaxis])

ax.plot(x_new, y_new)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

From this data:

```
BP Diastolic,BP Cystolic,A1C,BMI,Annual Income
140, 90, 5.7, 25, 60000
145, 95, 6.0, 30, 90000
140, 80, 5.9, 23, 45000
149, 85, 5.8, 24, 109000
130, 85, 5.8, 29, 34000
132, 90, 5.5, 24, 256000
139, 90, 5.4, 27, 67000
138, 87, 5.3, 27, 55000
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to see if we compute the linear regression parameters explicitly (this solution appends a column of ones to fit the bias term `b` in our `y = mx + b` solution, which lets us model the parameters as a vector `w` and the solution as a dot product: y = w<sup>T</sup>x):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[140,90,5.7,25,60000],
                 [145,95,6.0,30,90000],
                 [140,80,5.9,23,45000],
                 [149,85,5.8,24,109000],
                 [130,85,5.8,29,34000],
                 [132,90,5.5,24,256000],
                 [139,90,5.4,27,67000],
                 [138,87,5.3,27,55000]])
X = np.vstack([np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:, 0]]).T
y = data[:, 4]

# Compute Linear Regression parameters `w`
w = np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ (X.T @ y)

# Compute `y` for `x` in the range [130, 150]
x_new = np.vstack([np.ones(20), np.arange(130, 150)]).T
y_new = w @ x_new.T

plt.scatter(X[:, 1], y)
plt.plot(np.arange(130, 150), y_new)
plt.show()
```

Re-scaling with `MinMaxScaler` changes the scale of the data (here from ~50,000-250,000 to 0-1, and ~130-150 to 0-1), not the linear relationships between any points in the space. The linear regression solution depends on the inverse covariance and X<sup>T</sup>y, so you can rescale the solution to be the same in either space with a series of multiplications and additions (i.e. *linear* operations).

The [scikit-learn preprocessing guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) has some general advice on linear vs. non-linear feature transformation.

Result:

[image: Scatter plot with the same best fit line as the one shown in the question.]

---

As an alternative, if we use *nonlinear* methods to preprocess our data then some differences may exist. Here's an example based on `QuantileTransformer`:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

# data = np.array(...)
X = data[:, 0].reshape(-1, 1)
y = data[:, 4]

pipe = make_pipeline(QuantileTransformer(), LinearRegression()).fit(X, y)

x_new = np.sort(X[:, 0]).reshape(-1, 1)
plt.scatter(X, y)
plt.plot(x_new, pipe.predict(x_new))
```

[image: The points are in the same location, but the linear regression solution now looks like a wavy line.]